# R: Add Column with condition value is in vector (%in% or is.element on column)

Tags: r, analysis

I'm trying to add a column that will flag as TRUE when the column "market" contains "Belgium" or "Argentina".

```
id year quarter  market new_col_1 find_belgium_argentina<br>
1 2002      Q1 Belgium         1                  FALSE<br>
2 2002      Q1 Belgium         1                  FALSE<br>
3 2002      Q1 Belgium         1                  FALSE<br>
4 2002      Q1 Belgium         1                  FALSE<br>
5 2002      Q1 Belgium         1                  FALSE<br>
6 2002      Q1 Belgium         1                  FALSE<br>
```

I can do the trick with a single string like this >>>

```
d2["find_belgium_argentina"] = d2['market'] == "Belgium"
```

But... if I try these expressions they don't seem to work >>>

```
d2["find_belgium_argentina"] = d2["market"] %in% c("Belgium", "Argentina")

d2["find_belgium_argentina"] = is.element(d2["market"], c("Belgium", "Argentina"))
```

Any help would be great, I'm sure there must be an easy way to do it, I just couldn't figure it after reading several posts, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I figure what was wrong, I was using Pandas syntax, I should have used >>>

d2["find_belgium_argentina"] = d2**$market** %in% c("Belgium", "Argentina")

I'll try to delete the question, sorry about the inconvenience, thanks!

Comment: `d["foo"]` returns a data frame with one column. `d$foo` returns a vector of that column. You could also use double square brackets `d[["foo"]]` which also returns the vector, identically to `d$foo`. This is useful if you want to get a column by another level of indirection, eg: `z = "foo";d[[z]]` gets `d[["foo"]]`. Hard to do with dollar notation.

Answer (score 0):

I figure what was wrong, I was using Pandas syntax, I should have used >>> d2["find_belgium_argentina"] = d2**$market** %in% c("Belgium", "Argentina") I'll try to delete the question, sorry about the inconvenience, thanks!